# how to change the text color in uiwebview in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am parsing an rss feed and showing it in a webview I have set the background color of the webview as black using an image view.The parsed data is stored in a NSString...what I want is to change the textcolor,fontsize,fonttype of the string data..

```
self.itemTitle.text=[item objectForKey:@"title"];

[self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:[item objectForKey:@"description"] baseURL:nil];
[self.itemSummary setClipsToBounds:YES];

self.itemSummary.opaque=NO;

self.itemSummary.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body bgcolor=\"#000000\" text=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Bookman Old Style, Book Antiqua, Garamond\" size=\"5\">%@</body></html>", [item objectForKey:@"description"]] baseURL: nil];
```

You can use HTML colors.

---

Edit: added the text color.

---

Edit 2: added font size and face

Comment: i m not able to view the text its turned to complete black if i m use the above command

Comment: if the text color is also black then you won't see it... :) change the text color to something else, then it will work...

Comment: actually to be cleaner use CSS style ...
<html><body bgcolor=\"#000000\"><P style='color:white;'>%@</P></body></html>

Comment: wat i want is to change the text color.but changing the above value  has got no effect

Comment: Kenny: Thanks! kingston: check this new version.

Comment: style: face="Bookman Old Style, Book Antiqua, Garamond" and size: size="5"

Comment: @infite :could u update the above answer with style:face and size

Comment: Yes, I can, I will do it soon.

Comment: @infinite:i tried de above ...its not working the font and size remains the same

Answer (score 0):

To change the text/font/content color in UIWebView,you can use CSS Style property as suggested 
[here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp) ,i.e.:

```
[self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body p style='color:red' text=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Bookman Old Style, Book Antiqua, Garamond\" size=\"5\">%@</body></html>", [item objectForKey:@"description"]] baseURL: nil];
```

It worked for me,hope it also helps you,thanks :)